# I cannot update object property which is an array using push()method , I get Typescipt error that object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an onClick function which aim is to update currently existig array of objects (values), but precisely it will update only one property of the array(persons).

```
 const addPersonHandler = (index: number) => {
    if (!values.length) return;
    const val = values;
    const persons = val[index].persons;
    console.log('persons', persons);
    console.log('type', typeof persons);
    persons.push({
      name: '',
      lastName: '',
      type: '',
      cooperationForm: null,
    });
    console.log(persons);
  };
```

Here You can find what is persons property from first console.log and it's type
[image]

It makes me confused as persons looks like array, but it's type is object.
Due to that I cannot update persons property with .push() method and lower console.log() throws me an error like :
[image]

Line 80 from comment point directly to .push()method.
I'm wondering what is wrong and why persons has type of object as initial array of objects - values has type LuxmedsType. Below You can find how values is typed.

```
export type PersonType = {
      name: string;
      lastName: string;
      type: string;
      cooperationForm: string | null;
    };
    export type LuxmedsType = {
      luxmedType: {
        package: string;
        type: string;
        cost: number;
      };
      persons: PersonType[];
      companyCost: number;
      comment: null | string;
    };
```

Can You please suggest what is wrong here that persons type is object although should be an array ?

Comment: Note ,  Array is an object.  To test specially if it's an array its ,  `Array.isArray()`

Comment: It's can't be a TypeScript error, it's JS error, somewhere in your code might be: ```Object.preventExtensions(obj);``` called, which prevents extension of objects

Comment: It looks like `persons` has been frozen..  `Object.freeze()`..

Comment: Where do you get `values` from?

Comment: Anserwing Your all questions: 
when I console.log(Array.isArray(persons)) is returns true to me ; Object.preventExtensions(obj) or Object.freeze() don't exist in the app code.

Values I get from API call and it's array of objects

Comment: What "API call"? In any case, that makes it quite clear that the API is trying to prevent you from making mistakes by having frozen the array.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to recreate the array and push to that recreated array instead of the original array. As others have noted, somewhere along the line, `Object.freeze()` or `Object.preventExtensions(obj)` has been called (even if you haven't called it yourself in your source code)

```
const addPersonHandler = (index: number) => {
    if (!values.length) return;
    const val = values;
    const persons = val[index].persons;
    console.log('persons', persons);
    console.log('type', typeof persons);

    if (!Array.isArray(persons)) return;

    const newPersons = [...persons]
    newPersons.push({
      name: '',
      lastName: '',
      type: '',
      cooperationForm: null,
    });
    console.log(newPersons);
  };
```